# Why my powershell use the proxy 127.0.0.1:1080

Tags: windows, powershell

When I clone some git repo in powershell `git clone https://xxx`. The error show:

```
 Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 1080: Connection refused
```

But my proxy setting is set to port `7890` not `1080`.

My pc is windows. And in the `setting -> proxy` the proxy have been set to `7890`

And I have already set the proxy in powershell manually, by invoke the

```
$Env:http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:7890";$Env:https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:7890"
```

And my setting in `计算机\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer` is also `127.0.0.01:7890`.

Why it still look for `1080`. What else I can check. Thank you!

Update on 2012/3/7

The reason is my mistake that have set the git proxy. `git config --list` show

```
http.https://github.com.proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1080
```